# Bluetooth audio stream from android to electron app?

Tags: android, node.js, bluetooth, electron, audio-streaming

I'm currently building a Raspberry Pi Car PC with Electron. Nearly everything is done. Two things are remaining.

One of them is a Bluetooth audio stream from my mobile phone to the Electron app. Is there a way to do so via the "advanced audio" Bluetooth service of an Android phone? I want something like a Bluetooth speake where I can play/pause, skip, etc. songs.

The Bluetooth connection itself is not a problem. Already done that with an OBDII adapter to get a nice car health monitor.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you got the answer or you did the implementation?